# Different hash after relog

Tags: c#, hash, md5, tcpclient

I have very strange problem with my C# application. Basicaly, I am creating client <-> server application to send PDF files. I want to add MD5 checksum security to prevent unnecessary retransmissions. Here is my MD5 hasher:

```
public static class CardFingerprint
{
    static MD5 md5;

    static CardFingerprint()
    {
        md5 = MD5.Create();
    }

    public static string computeFingerprint(string pathToFile)
    {
        byte[] hash = null;

        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(pathToFile))
        {
            hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
        }

        return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", String.Empty);
    }
}
```

here is code for file receive, basicaly its tcpClient byte transmission:

```
        FileReceiverStatus status = fileReceiver.recieveFile(packetsToRecieve);
        string fingerPrint = CardFingerprint.computeFingerprint(status.DownloadedFile);
```

Everyting works fine, when I log into system and send file two times I'll get:

```
[ 06.01.2016 - 01:46:52 ] >> User: DELL-IKAROS sending file.
[ 06.01.2016 - 01:46:53 ] >> DELL-IKAROS: File Card_06012016_014653_9c93.pdf downloaded.
[ 06.01.2016 - 01:46:53 ] >> hash: 810E10B2770D2C3F89F89CAD9515567C
[ 06.01.2016 - 01:46:57 ] >> User: DELL-IKAROS sending file.
[ 06.01.2016 - 01:46:58 ] >> DELL-IKAROS: File Card_06012016_014658_fb78.pdf downloaded.
[ 06.01.2016 - 01:46:58 ] >> hash: 810E10B2770D2C3F89F89CAD9515567C
[ 06.01.2016 - 01:46:58 ] >> DELL-IKAROS: FILE DUPLICATION - CONTROLL SUM: 810E10B2770D2C3F89F89CAD9515567C
```

BUT!! When I log off and log in again, and send same file as before Ill get:

```
[ 06.01.2016 - 01:47:13 ] >> User: DELL-IKAROS log out.
[ 06.01.2016 - 01:47:16 ] >> User: DELL-IKAROS log in.
[ 06.01.2016 - 01:47:23 ] >> User: DELL-IKAROS sending file.
[ 06.01.2016 - 01:47:23 ] >> DELL-IKAROS: File Card_06012016_014723_7b15.pdf downloaded.
[ 06.01.2016 - 01:47:23 ] >> hash: B9C755B78472B71DD9D230C94CEF8FA6
```

What is going on??
Any clues what might be wrong? Downlaoded files have same numbers of bytes, there shouldn't be any difference except file name... Seems there is slighty difference but I have no idea why and where, if there would be problem in tcpClient downloader, then all md5 should be different, that problem occurs only after relog.

Comment: Can you get the hash for files from previous sessions to see which it then matches.  Is there a possibility that the file isnt completely written out yet?

Comment: I checked that, all files within one session have same MD5, when tcpClient changes, MD5 from files too, have no idea why. There is no possibility that file is not fully downloaded, hash is computed only when file is downloaded (Client will send "EOF", and server: "FIN" information). For now I simply replace MD5 with number of bytes in pdf file, works fine, but that MD5 functionallity will be much better.

Comment: Why don't you write the data out to disk and see what's different?

Comment: I did it with File.ReadAllBytes(), both files contain same data but MD5 throw different hash, very strange.

Comment: Please provide a code sample that reproduces your issue.